# Using LocalHost as Mail Server

Tags: c#, mail-server

I would like to install a local SMTP Server so that i can create a virtual domain and then create email address for that domain.

I would like to create SMTP details so that i can check the emails using thunderbird.

Also i must be able to send bulk mails to this server via C# code. This should not use the existing mail servers on the internet.

Suggest the good alternative

Comment: I don't really get how you expect your recipients to get your emails if you don't use any existing mail servers on the internet.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo: I just want this for testing purposes. So i only will send the email and will check the receipt of email in the thunderbird mail client. I donot want to go for external email servers.

Comment: What makes this a "valid" stackoverflow question? There is nothing about programming...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending the emails can be done in the way you describe. Just install an SMTP server, make sure you get all the details correct (hostname, portnumber, etc) and use that to send the emails.

Getting replies from people involves more work. You need a domainname for that, that is registered in a public DNS. On that domainname you need to set the correct MX record, which is a hostname or IP that points to your mail server. The mail server should be able to receive mail from the outside (the internet). In that mail server you probably need to configure the domain you are receiving for and the account you would like people to reply to.

BUT an SMTP server is different from a mail server. An SMTP Server is just for sending, but you need more than that when you also want to receive mail.

Comment: As i want to test my single and bulk emails, i just want to send email and view the sent emails, i will never receive emails from outside. This is for testing purpose only. Can you recommend a novice friendly SMTP Server.

Comment: I always use hMailServer, which supports mail sending and receiving and uses a simple SQL database to be configured. Using this I can easily configure mail accounts using code. But the SMTP server never let me down ;)

Comment: @Win Hassantra: Can you please tell me how you have set the route configuration to your localhost. I tried but not able to get the correct way. I want to create a local SMTP Host and receive mails there only.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the hMailServer, it was a cake for me and worked great. Thanks for sharing your idea and time Wim, this helped me a lot.